# If an operator have only Real eigenvalues + symmetric then it's self-adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

I know that if an operator is self-adjoint then has Real eigenvalues but I'm not sure about the converse i.e. if it has only Real eigenvalues and is symmetric then the operator is selfadjoint. Is that true?

**----Edit---**

The difference between selfadjoint and symmetric being the definition set. Symmetric has an extension which coincide in the original domain, while a Selfadjoint operator has the same domain of definition

I define **symmetric** as follows.
Let be $\mathcal{A}=\left(A,\mathfrak{D}_{A}\right)$
an operator densely defined and $\mathcal{A}^{*}=\left(A^{*},\mathfrak{D}_{A^{*}}\right)$ the adjoint operator, then $\mathcal{A}$ it is called ***symmetric*** if
\begin{eqnarray}
 &  & \mathfrak{D}_{A^{*}}\supseteq\mathfrak{D}_{A}\\
 &  & A^{*}\psi=A\psi\qquad\forall\psi\in\mathfrak{D}_{A}.
\end{eqnarray}

While I define **Self-adjoint** like this
Let be $\mathcal{A}=\left(A,\mathfrak{D}_{A}\right)$
an operator densely defined and $\mathcal{A}^{*}=\left(A^{*},\mathfrak{D}_{A^{*}}\right)$ the adjoint operator, then $\mathcal{A}$ it is called ***selfadjoint*** if
\begin{eqnarray}
 &  & \mathfrak{D}_{A^{*}}=\mathfrak{D}_{A}\\
 &  & A^{*}\psi=A\psi\qquad\forall\psi\in\mathfrak{D}_{A}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: sorry I forgot to add symmetric, now I edited the question

Comment: How do you define symmetric for an arbitrary operator?

Comment: ...what's is the difference between symmetric and self-adjoint?

Comment: Sorry I added the definitions I used...

Comment: Could be indeed interesting! But right now I'm interested in this problem how is it related?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is far from being true, indeed, every symmetric operator has only real eigenvalues:

If $\psi\in\ker(T-\lambda),\,\psi\neq 0$, then
$$
\lambda\|\psi\|^2=\langle T\psi,\psi\rangle=\langle \psi,T\psi\rangle=\bar\lambda\|\psi\|^2,
$$
hence $\lambda=\bar\lambda$.

Now every symmetric operator that is not self-adjoint yields a counterexample to your conjecture (if you want to be explicit, take $\Delta$ on $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as operator in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$).

To get a criterion for self-adjointness, you have to replace the eigenvalues by the spectrum of the operator. Then the following characterization holds:

A symmetric operator $T$ is self-adjoint if and only if its spectrum is contained in $\mathbb{R}$.

Proof: It suffices to show that $D(T^\ast)\subset D(T)$. Let $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$. Since $\sigma(T)\subset\mathbb{R}$, the operators $T-z$ and $T-\bar z$ are invertible.

Let $\phi\in D(T^\ast)$ and $\psi:=(T-z)^{-1}(T^\ast -z)\phi\in D(T)$. Then we have $T\psi=T^\ast\psi$ and $(T^\ast-z)\phi=(T-z)\psi$.

It follows that
$$
(T^\ast-z)(\phi-\psi)=(T-z)\psi-(T-z)\psi=0,
$$
that is, $\phi-\psi\in N(T^\ast-z)=R(T-\bar z)^\perp=\{0\}$. Hence, $\phi=\psi\in D(T)$.

Remark: I used $R(A)$ and $N(A)$ to denote the range and kernel of $A$.

Comment: Thank You Very Much!!! Could you also give me a sketch of the proof of if the spectrum is contained in R then it's self-adjoint?

Comment: Thank you again!!! Why does $\psi$ belong to D(T)?

Comment: Because $(T-z)^{-1}$ maps to $D(T)$ by definition.

Comment: True :D :D :D Perfect! Thank You

Comment: @MaoWao Could you please check whether the last edit to your post is correct? If yes: Could you please explain from where you get $T \psi = T^\ast \psi$, $(T^\ast - z) \psi = (T - z) \psi$ and $(T^\ast - z) (-\psi) = (T - z) \psi$? I can't see how you arrive there.

Comment: Also, don't you need $T$ to be closed here? I think that the converse inclusion $D(T) \subset D(T^\ast)$ is not true in general.

Comment: @Jan If $T$ is not closed, then $\sigma(T)=\mathbb{C}$, so $\sigma(T)\subset \mathbb{R}$ cannot happen in that case. Anyway, the inclusion $T\subset T^\ast$ holds for any densely defined symmetric operator (just play around a little with the definitions).

Comment: $T\psi=T^\ast \psi$ follows from $\psi\in D(T)$ and $T\subset T^\ast$. I don't think I claimed the third equality in your comment.

Comment: But if you have $(T^\ast - z)(\phi - \psi)$, then this is equal to $(T^\ast - z)(\phi) - (T^\ast - z)(\psi)$ and you are writing that this is equal to $(T - z) \psi - (T - z) \psi$. I see now the third equality I gave, but from where do you get that $(T^\ast - z)(\phi) = (T - z) \psi$?

Comment: Ah, there was a typo in your original comment. Just apply $T-z$ to $\psi$ and use the definition of $\psi$ to get this identity.

Comment: @MaoWao, $\psi$ is only well defined if $R(T^*-z) \subseteq R(T-z)$. Why does this inclusion hold?

Comment: @User1610788 As I said in the line before the definition of $\psi$, the operator $T-z$ is invertible by assumption. In particular, $R(T-z)$ is the full space.