# A multiplicative operator is self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

I am doing the following problem: Let $(M,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a general measure space, $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Define the operator $A_f:\mathrm{dom}(A_f)\to L^2(\mu)$ by $$\mathrm{dom}(A_f):=\{\psi\in L^2(\mu)|f\psi\in L^2(\mu)\}$$ $$A_f\psi=f\psi,\forall\psi\in\mathrm{dom}(A_f)$$ Show this operator is self-adjoint for any given measurable function $f$.

It is clear that this operator is symmetric, but I can't think of any method to argue the domain of $A^*_f$ is the same as that of $A_f$ (I know it's at least larger so we only need to prove $\mathrm{dom}(A^*_f)\subset\mathrm{dom}(A_f)$). By definition I can have $$\left<A_f^*\psi,\phi\right>=\left<\psi,A_f\phi\right>=\left<\psi,f\phi\right>=
\left<f\psi,\phi\right>,\forall \phi\in\mathrm{dom}(A_f)$$
so $A^*_f\psi=f\psi,\forall \psi\in\mathrm{dom}(A^*_f)$. 
However it doesn't seem to help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can show $A_f^\ast \psi=f\psi$, you are done (since $A_f^\ast \psi\in L^2$ by definition). However, this does not follow immediately from the equality
$$
\langle A_f^\ast \psi,\phi\rangle=\int f\psi\phi\,d\mu.
$$
because $f\psi$ is a priori only a measurable function and not in $L^2$ (that's what you want to prove).

I think the easiest way to prove self-adjointness here is to show that $A_f\pm i$ is invertible. Just verify that $A_{(f\pm i)^{-1}}$ is the inverse.

Comment: I am not so clear about that, nothing requires $A_f^*\psi$ to be in $L^2$.

Comment: We just know $\psi$ is in the domain of $A_f^*$, but it doesn't mean $A_f^*\psi$ is also in $L^2$. Though the definition of $A_f$ requires $f\phi$ to be square integrable given $\phi\in\mathrm{dom}(A_f)$

Comment: The adjoint is an (unbounded) operator on $L^2$. In particular, it maps into $L^2$.

Comment: I mean even with $A^*_f\psi=f\psi$. It is still not valid to show $A_f^*\psi\in L^2$

Comment: Once again: If $T$ is a densely defined operator on the Hilbert space $H$, then $T^\ast$ is an operator on $H$. This is just the definition of the adjoint.

Comment: Ohh, I think I get your point. Thanks!

Comment: If $A_f+i$ and $A_f-i$ are invertible, how does this imply that $A_f$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: That's a well-known criterion for self-adjointness. My answer here essentially gives the proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617923/if-an-operator-have-only-real-eigenvalues-symmetric-then-its-self-adjoint/1618022#1618022. Note that by the resolvent formula, invertibility for some $z$ in the upper half plane gives invertibility for all $z$ in the upper half-plane, and likewise for the lower half plane.